# Gauss-Kronrod quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

I am writing a thesis on the adaptive Gauss-Kronrod quadrature rule.
In the last part I am exposing some numerical results, and I found this little problem: since in the adaptive algorithm we use as an estimate for the error the absolute value of the difference between the Gauss formula and the Gauss-Kronrod formula, in the results I found that the estimate is bigger than the actual error (the difference between the exact result and the Gauss-Kronrod result).
Is this result plausible?